# Let each plot in facet_grid have its own Y-axis value

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently I'm having trouble with displaying the chart Y-axis to my likings. What I want is that each separate plot shows the point width that depends on its own score. See the image below to see what I've got and what I want.

[image]

Basically, I want each plot to be dependent on its own index, i.e. Silhouette, Davies-Bouldin etc. Just like the first graph (Carlinski-Harabasz on the left) is showing.

This is the data and the code so far

```
algorithms <- as.factor(c(rep("kmeans", 4), rep("pam", 4), rep("cmeans", 4)))
index <- as.factor(c(rep("Silhouette", 12), rep("Carlinski-Harabasz", 12)
, rep("Davies-Bouldin",12)))
score <- c(0.12,0.08,0.07,0.05,0.1,0.07,0.09,0.08,0.13,0.11,0.1,0.1,142,106,84,74,128,
99,91,81,156,123,105,95,2.23,2.31,2.25,2.13,2.55,2.12,2.23,2.08,2.23,2.12,2.17,1.97)
clusters <- as.factor(rep(3:6,9))
indices <- data.frame(algorithms, index, score, clusters)

#Some ggplot code
ggplot(indices, aes(clusters, score)) + 
geom_point(aes(size = score, color = algorithms)) + 
facet_grid(.~index, scales = "free_y") 
#I thought the scales function in facet grid might do the trick...
```

To my understanding I have to work around the Y-axis scale. However, this proves to be quite tricky for me.

### Updated answer

```
ggplot(indices, aes(clusters, score)) + 
geom_point(aes(size = score, color = algorithms)) + 
facet_wrap(~index, scales = "free_y")
```

Did the trick. Thanks for pointing it out.

### Updated answer 2nd

In addition, thanks to camille, a better visualization is to use `facet_grid` with 2 variables. Therefore, the final code will be:

```
ggplot(indices, aes(clusters, score)) + 
geom_point() + facet_grid(index ~ algorithms, scales = "free_y") + 
theme_bw() + labs(y="Score per index", x="Clusters")
```

Comment: try using `facet_wrap`

Comment: `facet_grid(.~index, scales = "free_y")`  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had this problem, and realized the scales have slightly different interpretations: in `facet_grid`, the scales are free to change *per row / column of facets*, whereas with `facet_wrap`, the scales are free to change *per facet*, since there isn't a hard & fast meaning given to the rows or columns. Think of it like `grid` does macro-level scaling and `wrap` does micro-level.

One advantage that `facet_grid` has is quickly putting all values of one variable in a row or column together, making it easy to see what's going on. But you can mimic that in `facet_wrap` by setting the facets up on a single row or column, as I did below with `nrow = 1`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

algorithms <- as.factor(c(rep("kmeans", 4), rep("pam", 4), rep("cmeans", 4)))
index <- as.factor(c(rep("Silhouette", 12), rep("Carlinski-Harabasz", 12)
                     , rep("Davies-Bouldin",12)))
score <- c(0.12,0.08,0.07,0.05,0.1,0.07,0.09,0.08,0.13,0.11,0.1,0.1,142,106,84,74,128,
           99,91,81,156,123,105,95,2.23,2.31,2.25,2.13,2.55,2.12,2.23,2.08,2.23,2.12,2.17,1.97)
clusters <- as.factor(rep(3:6,9))
indices <- data.frame(algorithms, index, score, clusters)


ggplot(indices, aes(clusters, score)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = score, color = algorithms)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ index, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(indices, aes(clusters, score)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = score, color = algorithms)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ index, scales = "free_y", nrow = 1)
```

[image]

The difference is more clear when you're using `facet_grid` with two variables. Using the `mpg` dataset from `ggplot2`, this first plot doesn't have free scales, so each row's y-axis has tick marks between 10 and 35. That is, the y-axes *of each row of facets* are fixed. With `facet_wrap`, this scaling would take place for each facet.

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(class ~ fl)
```

[image]

Setting `scales = "free_y"` in `facet_grid` means that *each row of facets* can set its y-axis independent of the other rows. So, for example, all facets of compact cars are subject to one y-scale, but they're unaffected by the y-scale of pickups.

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(class ~ fl, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: First of all, nice explanation between both. Since the ggplot2 cheat sheet does not really tell it. I must say that, using  `nrow = 1` in combination with `position = "jitter"` does not improve reading the chart. For example, in my dataset a few points have the same outcome. Therefore, it becomes unclear which point belongs to which cluster.

It is interesting to see that the last option you mention is pretty neat. In fact, it visualizes it great. I will update my answer (again) and accept the answer provided.